# At what point will you have access to all buildings?

Tags: protolife

When I was running my first Experiment in *Protolife* the initial base layout included a setup for generating crystals, but instead of the normal 3x3 square i have been using it was a 4x4 square so it created 4 crystals.

When I went back to the main game figuring this would be much better (and cheaper) to generate crystals for my turrets I tried it but it didn't work which makes me think that later building/turrets don't become available until they are introduced in the level select.

So I would like to know at what point will you have access to all buildings?

Answer (score 1):

Protolife developer here.

Yes, the new buildings become available as you go over campaign missions. In experiments you have all buildings available from start.